# "[Father] to whom [Son] was born" is acceptable?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this phrase grammatically correct? Does it sound natural?

> [Father's Name] to whom [Son's Name] was born.

My other attempts were:

> [Father's Name] of/from whom was born [Son's Name].

Here "of" sounds right to me but "from" sounds wrong, this might be because I relate "from" to places instead of people.

Also: if I write

> ...whom was born [Son's Name] and his brothers.

Must 'was' become 'were'?

Comment: Mothers bear young, not fathers. Fathers sire or beget them.

Comment: Thanks @tchrist, couldn't the phrase be understood as "[Father's Name] to whom [Son's Name] was born through [Mother's Name]"?

Comment: I don't think either sire or beget is common in modern English, at least for people.  The most likely verb is "father": "[father's name] fathered [son's name]."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application of 'to whom was born [son's name]' is not solely applied to mothers:

> 148: 5. *I will now treat of the Hebrews. The son of Phaleg, whose*
> *father Was Heber, was Ragau; whose son was Serug, to whom was born*
> *Nahor;*

[[The Antiquities of the Jews, 1.122–1.153
Flavius Josephus  translated by William Whiston](https://lexundria.com/j_aj/1.122-1.153/wst)]

> *Charles Chidongo Chinula was born in 1885 at Mthimba village in Mzimba district. His father was a brave Ngoni warrior to whom was born
> a frail male child ...*

[[Dictionary of African Christian Biography](https://dacb.org/stories/malawi/chinula-charles/)]

> ... *Bible belonging to William White and his wife, to whom was born
> the first child in New England, Peregrine White* ... ['whom' is
> infelicitous if referring only to Mrs White]

[[New York Times; 1890](https://www.newspapers.com/article/the-new-york-times-william-whites-bible/133865246/)]

> *In a very humble cottage in a small village called Paulerspury, about three miles from Towcester, in Northampton, England, lived a worthy
> young couple to whom was born on August 17, 1761, their oldest child,
> William Carey.*

[[William Carey: The Father of Modern Missions
by Galen B. Royer](https://www.wholesomewords.org/missions/bcarey3.html)]

But the expression is dated, or at least used nowadays to impart a classical/historical flavour; 'who had a son/daughter named ...' is idiomatic nowadays.

...................

... *to whom Ø born X and Y / X, Y and ...* etc certainly need Ø = were. Compare

... *to whom were introduced Fred and his sisters*

=

... *to whom Fred and his sisters were introduced*.

... *to whom Fred and his sisters was born* is obviously incorrect.